# left of .length must have class/struct/nnion

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am new to c++ and programming as a whole, and I am doing an assignment where I have created a class, Person, which contains variables for forname, surname and age. This works without fine, but my problem arises when I pass the class vector to my linear search function, where I get the error "left of .end must have class/Struct/union". I do not know why, and after googling for about an hour I decided to instead ask.

```
int linsok(Person p[], int n, int a)
{
  cout << "Please enter the age of the person you want to find: ";
  cin >> a;

  for (n = 0; n < p->Person::Person.end(); n++)
  {
    if ( a = p->Person::Person.setAge)
    {
        cout << "The person you are looking for has the position " << n 
        << " in the list." << endl;
    }
    else
        return -1;

  }}
```

To clarify, my assignment is to create a linear search that searches through the vector to find the age of a person that matches the search criteria: a, and to return -1 if no person with that age was found.

Comment: The error message is because `Person::Person` is not the name of an instance of a struct type.    There are also several other problems in your code to, which you haven't asked about.   To the extent that makes it obvious you are relying on guesswork, rather than any understanding of C++.  In particular, `Person p[]` is not the way to pass a vector in C++.   Try listening in class and reading any notes or reference materials BEFORE trying to write code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `p` isn't an `std::vector`, it's just a plain old array. The `n` argument should denote its size, so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // Code...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Person p[]` is an array. Unlike `std::vector<Person>`, it does not provide a way to determine its length through a property. That is why `n` is passed to your function, presumably to specify the number of elements in the array. The loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
```

You refer to person's age as follows:

```
p[i].age // or getAge(), I don't see you Person's class
```

**Note:** Scope resolution `::` syntax is somewhat more advanced. It is needed to specify which function to call or which type to use inside a particular namespace. For the most part, you can ignore it for now.